# WP_Session plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

So I've Googled and read myself to death and can't find a solution to this problem.

I'm using the [WP Session Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/) to use session data. We need a very specific social login and register flow. We have a Wordpress site (version 4.2.1) at www.domain.com and our web app is located at app.domain.com. Now if you log in or register on the WP site, you are logged in / registered on the app (not the WP site).

I'm writing a custom plugin for this as the options out there does not fulfill my needs.

My issue comes in with accessing the session data between functions. My flow is as follow (using Google as an example):

User clicks Google+ login, popup with Google Authentication pops up, user gives permission, callback url is `www.domain.com/google_callback`. The page `google_callback` has a shortcode called `google_callback` which then calls the function. Everything in that function works and I get the data back properly. With all the Google data handling stripped away, that function looks like this:

```
// social.php plugin file
function google_callback() {
    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
    // Get Google data all happens here...
    $user['name']     = $userObj->givenName;
    $user['surname']  = $userObj->familyName;
    $user['email']    = $userObj->email;
    $user['verified'] = $userObj->verifiedEmail;
    $wp_session['registeruser'] = $user;
    $wp_session['registertype'] = 'Google';
    wp_redirect(home_url('social-register'));
}
```

Now if I `var_dump($wp_session);` just before `wp_redirect`, I get all the Google data correctly.

The `social-register` page has a shortcode that builds a form and pre-populates it with the retrieved data. This is that function:

```
// theme functions.php file
function build_registerform($args,$content=null) {
    $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
    var_dump($wp_session);
}
```

At this `var_dump`, `$wp_sessio`n is an empty `WP_Session object`.

I have tried changing all the `$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();` to `global $wp_session` with no luck.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found any solution? How did you manage sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think in your social.php **you will first have to make $wp_session global out side any function**. So on the top of the social.php, after including scripts. add this

```
global $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
```

Then later on in the google_callback function just use

```
global $wp_session;
```

Similarly in your theme functions.php

```
function build_registerform($args,$content=null) {
    global $wp_session;
    var_dump($wp_session); //session is empty right now
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. I have tried what you said but get an empty object.

Comment: I think functions.php might have a higher priority and is called before the plugin file. How about adding the build_registerform directly in soclal.php

Comment: Did you find this working?? It's an empty object each time I get, and `global $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();` showing syntax error!

Comment: I get: WP_Session::get_instance was called incorrectly. Please use native Session functionality. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your session manager plugin is working or not.

Activate your plugin and add this code in your `functions.php` file

```
function test_session () {
 global $wp_session;
 $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
}
add_action( 'init', 'test_session' );
```

then add this code in your `header.php` file

```
<?php
global $wp_session;
$wp_session['test'] = "test";
var_dump($wp_session);
?>
```

Comment: I get: WP_Session::get_instance was called incorrectly. Please use native Session functionality. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP WARNING: WP_Session::get_instance was called incorrectly. Please use native Session functionality.
```

I replaced `$wp_sess = WP_Session::get_instance();` with `$wp_sess $_SESSION;` That would seem to satisfy the native Session part of the error.  I did this one by one to check for any extra errors.

Then if there are any writes to `$wp_sess`: example `$wp_sess['error'] = 'some error';` add:

```
$_SESSION = $wp_sess;
```

at the end of the function.

Alternatively replace `$wp_sess` with `$_SESSION`, although I got errors doing so with a find and replace.